# using curl with simplehtmldom

Tags: php

Recently our hosting disabled allow_url_fopen, it seems simplehtmldom needs it turned on I saw a work arround with allow_url_fopen in this site simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net...aq.htm#hosting, "Use curl to get the page, then call "str_get_dom" to create DOM object". but still to no luck. can you tell me if I did it properly or am I missing something?

```
<?php 
$curl = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'www.weather.bm/');   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);   
$str = curl_exec($curl);   
curl_close($curl);   
$html= str_get_html($str);  
?> 
<?php  
$element = $html->find("div");  
$element[66]->class = "mwraping66"; 
foreach($html->find('.mwraping66 img') as $e) 

$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML( $e );  $containers = pq('.mwraping66', $doc);    
foreach ( $containers as $container ) {     $div = pq('img', $container);       
$div->eq(1)->removeAttr('style')->addClass('thumbnail')->html( pq( 'img', $div->eq(1))-    >removeAttr('height')->removeAttr('width')->removeAttr('alt') );  
}  print $doc;  
?> 
<?php  
$element = $html->find("div");   
$element[31]->class = "mwraping31";  
foreach($html->find('.mwraping31') as $e)  
echo $e->plaintext;   
?>.................................
```

compared to:

```
<?php 
include('simple_html_dom.php'); 
include ('phpQuery.php');    
// Create DOM from URL 
$html = file_get_html('www.weather.bm/'); 
?> 
<?php  
$element = $html->find("div");  
$element[66]->class = "mwraping66"; 
foreach($html->find('.mwraping66 img') as $e).....
```

Thanks you for your help

Comment: You can likely reenable allow_url_fopen via .htaccess. As for your curl snippet, you should pass a complete http:// url to CURLOPT_URL, not just a domain name.

Comment: I tried .htaccess but did not work It seems our hosting disabled it permanently, as for the http:// I just forgot to include it in the post sorry.

Comment: i also have  same doubt...if any one knew answer please post

Answer (score 1):

I know this is too late to answer this query but i have found similar questions and answer in this forum.. this is the link to that [Using simple html dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239391/using-simple-html-dom) .. i am not sure whether this will answer your query because i am also new to dom .try to use this modified simple_html_dom.php file http://webarto.com/82/php-simple-html-dom-curl it uses curl instead of file_get_content; this file is working for me and its usage is also same as the original simple_html_dom.php