# Using simple html dom

Tags: php, curl

hi
Using this code with simplehtmldom script (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm):
I got some error with it:

> failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed!

I think should be use curl instead  of file_get_contents in this script.
Anyone have an idea how to inser curl in this script?

Comment: We need some more information. Do you have your actual file? There is more than 1 simple html dom script.

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(http://example.com/new/id_123.html) failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/simple_html_dom.php on line 40

where line 40 is  $dom->load(call_user_func_array('file_get_contents', $args), true);

Comment: You can download the version with CURL from http://webarto.com/82/php-simple-html-dom-curl

Answer (score 1):

There is a `simple_html_dom` version that already implement cURL instead `file_get_contents` [found here](http://webarto.com/82/php-simple-html-dom-curl).

I use this version changing `file_get_html` function in its ->load call like this:

```
$dom->load(getWithCurl($args[0]));
```

with `getWithCurl` function taken from [get remote HTML with cURL and PHP](http://blog.ryanrampersad.com/2008/11/07/get-remote-html-with-curl-and-php/).

it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_data($url)
{
 $ch = curl_init();
 $timeout = 5;
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return $data;
}
$url = 'http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm';
echo $data = get_data($url);
```

Comment: oh thnx but how to integrate this with simplehtmldom?

Comment: @goni all above is php code, gives you data as string, try string functions and we can break it.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the examples under the PHP curl manual:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php

Unlike many manuals, the PHP manual is actually extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in my CentOS

```
yum install php-mbstring
yum install php-xml
yum install php-xmlrpc
```

every thing worked after that with simple_html_dom class